# How do install iPhone application from Xcode to a remote iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, installation

is there a possibility to install an application from Xcode to a remote iPhone? I have the dev account and able to install it locally.

I am currently in Sydney and would like to install a prototype of a game on the device of a coworker in Germany. The work is still in progress so it's has to be done quite often...

Is there a way to do this without jailbreak?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 16):

I think you've got two options:

1. Use AdHoc distribution to compile a copy with a special provisioning profile that allows him to install it on his device through iTunes. AdHoc distribution allow you to share your application with up to 100 other iPhone or iPod touch users, and you can share your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server.
2. Set him up as a member of your development group in Apple's Program Portal (requires business-level membership) and then send him the entire source folder for your project and let him build it. He could check it out of version control and build it without too much hassle.

I'd opt for option 1, though you need to setup ad-hoc provisioning profiles for your project in the Program Portal, which can be kind of a pain.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a method called ad-hoc distribution.

You need to add the offsite phone to your applicaiton's provisioning profile, (you will need it's UUID to do that), once you have built and signed the application you send a zip file that contains the .app created by Xcode and a copy of the  .mobileprovision file to your co-worker.

He drags them both into iTunes, the app should then show up and he syncs it onto his phone.

Look into the apple iPhone Dev center for more info

Answer (score 3):

If you're still looking -> http://testflightapp.com ;)

TestFlightApp is a webapp tool which allow you creating teams (you give a recruit link) and then you can manage members. Promote a tester as developper and the contrary.
When you upload a build (.ipa), then all your teammates (from every team you push the build for) will receive an email to tell them the new build and changelog, and the webapp will allow them install or upgrade the new build.

Very interesting.

Comment: testflight is great, but it seems you still need to physically connect the device once to get xcode to add it to the team/app provision profile. also, seems we always have to manually install the app via the buildbox once before testflight installs work.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for you coworker UUID and add him as a Beta tester for your app in your Developper Portal.

you'll be able to send a zip file which can be install on the targeted iPhone,
full step by step :
http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/

[edit]
If your coworker is also developper and you just want him/her to test the binary without seeing the source code, he/she can resign the application bundle:
[resign a application (TUAW)](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/06/24/dev-corner-signing-iphone-apps-for-informal-distribution/)

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://iphone.farook.org/faqs/how-do-i-install-an-ad-hoc-distribution.html) has a really good walk through for Windows and iTunes installation. Along with making sure you drag the .app folder (not the zip), this is probably the most important part of the process - dragging into the library not the device:

[alt text http://iphone.farook.org/images/faqs/adhoc-3.png](http://iphone.farook.org/images/faqs/adhoc-3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your coworker would need an Apple Developer license and would need to go though the standard process.

Alternatively, I believe it'd have to go though the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a license too, to create provision proviles (like the Ad-Hoc provision profile as described above). But if you have, you have to create that, enable it in your project as provision-profile for build "Ad-Hoc" (if doesn't exists, make one) and build it to a device (only build, not build-and-go). Mail the product and the ad-hoc provision profile to your friend, and let him drag both files to iTunes. Now he can sync and install the app on his device.

Don't forget to add his device-identifier to your ad-hoc provision profile.