# share ipa file xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, share, ipa

If I create an .ipa file and send it to another person. Can he open it in iTunes just clicking on it ? And can he install in just clicking on it ?

Answer (score 1):

For up to 100 new people per year, yes - assuming their device has been added to the Ad Hoc provisioning profile that you have signed the .ipa file with.

See the [developer documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html)

Comment: to create this add hoc thing,can i do it immediately?or do i have to wait for apples approval?

Comment: No approval is needed and no ad-hoc profile is needed either. You can just add the device id's of the recipients of the ipa in any profile you use in debug or release.

Comment: Sure - see link added to my answer. Plenty of results if you google too.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
There is a tool called TestFlightApp, i've explained it there: [How do install iPhone application from Xcode to a remote iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123021/how-do-install-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-remote-iphone/8408284#8408284)

Answer (score 0):

After numerous headaches trying to share apps with people I do work for, i created what i consider the easiest way to share ipa files.  [http://www.ipashare.com](http://ipashare.com)

Pretty much just drag and drop your ipa file onto the webpage and it will generate a short url that you send to the person you want to install the app.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You **don't need** AdHoc or registering the device UDID.

Comment: This seems wrong to me. I believe you do need to register the UDID.

Comment: Huh? What did I write? Yes, you're totally right. Don't know what I thought on then.