# Is there a way to install an ipa file to tester without all the apple stuff?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipa, provisioning-profile

I have some ipa files and it turns out that I can install directly on my device without having to do anything unusual, just itunes. These apps are not in the app store, so I guess they've done something with Xcode or with the ipas, right? How is this possible?

When I pass the apps I've done to some beta testers I have to ask IDs and after putting it in the certificate, it can be installed, but if not, no.

So anyone have any idea? What happened?

If you have an Enterprise account, you still need the ID's of the testers, right?

sorry for my bad english, but at least I try!

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: No, the device isn't jailbroken.

Comment: Looking for some more info about enterprise program I found that the id's are not required to distribute in-house apps (which I don't know exactly what does mean). Could be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

We can do in Xcode "build and archive", which will then create an ipa file. This is done by the developers to pass on the app to the client for testing or reviewing.

Ofcourse, if you want to run this archive your device should have been added in the provisioning profile with which the archive was created.

Comment: I know, this is why I don't understand what have they done! Every time I have to send my apps to betatester if I haven't its ID's I can't do anything..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you look at [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com/)?</strike>

**EDIT**

Come to think of it, if one is able to give their applications to anonymous testers he could sell the app outside the AppStore. That would be counterproductive for Apple and unless the user jailbreaks the device it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Test Flight still requires device IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak said (then stroke), you can use TestFlightApp (you won't have to care about UDID).
Explained there: [How do install iPhone application from Xcode to a remote iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123021/how-do-install-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-remote-iphone/8408284#8408284)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install that from Safari, of course that you have to do the provisioning profiles and everything else on normal account for apple procedures. But there is a way to install your app without iTunes if you have a valid .ipa file.
You can put this file on your server and put a HTML with directly link with IP and use this HTML exemple substituting the informations for yours servers and files information:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>

<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://SERVER_IP/URL_IPA_FILE/IPA.plist">
        Install App</a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

So you have to use the manifest.plist created by xcode when you create a .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

the best and easiest way is to use [diawi.com](http://diawi.com), no account/registration required.

Comment: How trust worthy is diawi.com?  Has anyone had problems with it?

Comment: i always use diawi to send demo app for client, because it is very easy to use.. and free. no problem so far