# How to install project ipa file on iPhone query?

Tags: iphone, xcode3.2, ipa

I have created Map application for iPhone using xcode 3.2 and sdk 4.3.2. I have created
ipa file and send it to my client. But he is unable to run my project on his iPod. What are 
the steps to follow for my client to run an project ipa file. Do my client need to jailbroke his device????

Comment: You'll need to follow Apple's provisioning steps for ad hoc deployment. See the provisioning portal in your iOS dev center for instructions.

Comment: Which details should I take from my client.

Comment: And how can my client get his UUID.????

Comment: Ok my client has gave me his iPod UUID. My application is for iPhone. Is there any trobul. Will he be able to run this on ipod. This is my first applicaiton that why I have so many queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open iTunes, drag the ipa to the library and then sync the device. Make sure the app is selected to be installed on the device.

The only other thing I can think of, is that his device is not provisioned to run the application. Have him give you the UDID, add him to the provisioning profile and then make another build if the first solution does not work.

And no he doesn't need to jail break his device.

Comment: Which all details should I take from my client to share my app with him. And how can my client get his UUID.????

Comment: Ok my client has gave me his iPod UUID. My application is for iPhone. Is there any trobul. Will he be able to run this on ipod. This is my first applicaiton that why I have so many queries

Comment: No problem. We've all been through the hell of getting our apps to run on a device. You are a licensed developer right? Can't load on device if not. 

He should be able to run it on any device given that his device is in the list of devices, this can be done by going to developer.apple.com ->provisioning portal ->devices and then selecting add device.

After you do that you'll have to add the device to your provisioning profile. This is done in the provisioning portal, select the provisioning tab on the side and then your profile and then select edit and modify and then select his device.

Comment: Hi friend I am facing new problem .........My client has successfully test my beta project file in December. But now I recently sent my updated ipa file to him.....only splash screen get open and app closed on iPod at my client end. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong. Well at my end the code get run but when I try with ipa file I am facing the same problem. My project ipa file is not running?????

Comment: At this point I'm just making uneducated guesses since there's not much info to base my guess on. Does the app work on the device when you run it from xcode? Also make sure everything in the ipa is appropriately named with the proper case. Just a guess.

Comment: yep app work on the device by xcode. I have check app with instrument tool and come to know abt memory leaks. I was unaware of the fact before. I reduced some of this leaks. Only on parsing 100% mem leaks are coming. I am assuming this is the problem and put question for the same on....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860576/how-to-remove-parsing-and-nsplaceholdermutablestring-frame-leaks-in-iphone. Can you suggest me the proper logic on same. Thanks for follow up

Answer (score 1):

don't jailbreak!
use testflightapp.com   :)

follow their directions, and make sure you register your client's device and update your provisioning profiles when building your app.

good luck!

Comment: Hi friend I am facing new problem .........My client has successfully test my beta project file in December. But now I recently sent my updated ipa file to him.....only splash screen get open and app closed on iPod at my client end. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong. Well at my end the code get run but when I try with ipa file I am facing the same problem. My project ipa file is not running?????

Answer (score 0):

if you have a developper licence, you should try TestFlightApp.com.
I've just explained what's this tool there: [How do install iPhone application from Xcode to a remote iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123021/how-do-install-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-remote-iphone/8408284#8408284)